# RabbitMQ 3.6.1 / Erlang 18.3 TLS insufficient security failures

Tags: java, spring, erlang, rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ 3.6.1/Erlang 18.3, and find that I am unable to establish a TLSv1 or TLSv1.1 session with the broker using the Spring AMQP 1.5.4.RELEASE Java client.  I am, however, able to establish a TLSv1.2 session with the broker.  My RabbitMQ broker is configured to support all three of tlsv1, tlsv1.1, and tlsv1.2.  I am using Java 1.8.0_77-b03 on OS X.

Here is my RabbitMQ configuration:

https://gist.github.com/ae6rt/de06d1efecf62fbe8cef31774d9be3d7

Erlang on the broker reports ssl versions

```
# erl                                                                                                                                                                                 
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> ssl:versions().
[{ssl_app,"7.3"},
 {supported,['tlsv1.2','tlsv1.1',tlsv1]},
 {available,['tlsv1.2','tlsv1.1',tlsv1,sslv3]}]
```

This is the error RabbitMQ logs upon failure:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 22-Apr-2016::03:19:02 ===
SSL: hello: tls_handshake.erl:167:Fatal error: insufficient security
```

I used tcpdump to sniff the traffic on the secure port 5671 during TLS setup.  Here is tshark's formatting of that data:

```
Frame 4: 210 bytes on wire (1680 bits), 210 bytes captured (1680 bits)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Apr 21, 2016 20:09:38.053439000 PDT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1461294578.053439000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.013675000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.013840000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 4
    Frame Length: 210 bytes (1680 bits)
    Capture Length: 210 bytes (1680 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssl]
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:f5:68:bc:7c (02:42:f5:68:bc:7c), Dst: 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (02:42:ac:11:00:02)
    Destination: 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (02:42:ac:11:00:02)
        Address: 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (02:42:ac:11:00:02)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: 02:42:f5:68:bc:7c (02:42:f5:68:bc:7c)
        Address: 02:42:f5:68:bc:7c (02:42:f5:68:bc:7c)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.0.2.2, Dst: 172.17.0.2
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 196
    Identification: 0x0a1e (2590)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 63
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0xb901 [validation disabled]
        [Good: False]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 10.0.2.2
    Destination: 172.17.0.2
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 39141 (39141), Dst Port: 5671 (5671), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 156
    Source Port: 39141
    Destination Port: 5671
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 156]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 157    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: *******AP***]
    Window size value: 65535
    [Calculated window size: 65535]
    [Window size scaling factor: -2 (no window scaling used)]
    Checksum: 0x6ef9 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [iRTT: 0.000165000 seconds]
        [Bytes in flight: 156]
Secure Sockets Layer
    SSL Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 151
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 147
            Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
            Random
                GMT Unix Time: Apr 21, 2016 20:09:38.000000000 PDT
                Random Bytes: 742380f15c78a0409bd2817911699637f5c7879f27bf6dc1...
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 44
            Cipher Suites (22 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 62
            Extension: elliptic_curves
                Type: elliptic_curves (0x000a)
                Length: 52
                Elliptic Curves Length: 50
                Elliptic curves (25 curves)
                    Elliptic curve: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Elliptic curve: sect163k1 (0x0001)
                    Elliptic curve: sect163r2 (0x0003)
                    Elliptic curve: secp192r1 (0x0013)
                    Elliptic curve: secp224r1 (0x0015)
                    Elliptic curve: sect233k1 (0x0006)
                    Elliptic curve: sect233r1 (0x0007)
                    Elliptic curve: sect283k1 (0x0009)
                    Elliptic curve: sect283r1 (0x000a)
                    Elliptic curve: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Elliptic curve: sect409k1 (0x000b)
                    Elliptic curve: sect409r1 (0x000c)
                    Elliptic curve: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                    Elliptic curve: sect571k1 (0x000d)
                    Elliptic curve: sect571r1 (0x000e)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160k1 (0x000f)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160r1 (0x0010)
                    Elliptic curve: secp160r2 (0x0011)
                    Elliptic curve: sect163r1 (0x0002)
                    Elliptic curve: secp192k1 (0x0012)
                    Elliptic curve: sect193r1 (0x0004)
                    Elliptic curve: sect193r2 (0x0005)
                    Elliptic curve: secp224k1 (0x0014)
                    Elliptic curve: sect239k1 (0x0008)
                    Elliptic curve: secp256k1 (0x0016)
            Extension: ec_point_formats
                Type: ec_point_formats (0x000b)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)

Frame 6: 61 bytes on wire (488 bits), 61 bytes captured (488 bits)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Apr 21, 2016 20:09:38.053842000 PDT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1461294578.053842000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000377000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000403000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.014243000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 6
    Frame Length: 61 bytes (488 bits)
    Capture Length: 61 bytes (488 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssl]
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (02:42:ac:11:00:02), Dst: 02:42:f5:68:bc:7c (02:42:f5:68:bc:7c)
    Destination: 02:42:f5:68:bc:7c (02:42:f5:68:bc:7c)
        Address: 02:42:f5:68:bc:7c (02:42:f5:68:bc:7c)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (02:42:ac:11:00:02)
        Address: 02:42:ac:11:00:02 (02:42:ac:11:00:02)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.17.0.2, Dst: 10.0.2.2
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 47
    Identification: 0x3fb8 (16312)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x42fc [validation disabled]
        [Good: False]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 172.17.0.2
    Destination: 10.0.2.2
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 5671 (5671), Dst Port: 39141 (39141), Seq: 1, Ack: 157, Len: 7
    Source Port: 5671
    Destination Port: 39141
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 7]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 8    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 157    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: *******AP***]
    Window size value: 30016
    [Calculated window size: 30016]
    [Window size scaling factor: -2 (no window scaling used)]
    Checksum: 0xb836 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [iRTT: 0.000165000 seconds]
        [Bytes in flight: 7]
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Insufficient Security)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Insufficient Security (71)
```

Here is the Spring connection failure:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: insufficient_security
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:134)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:277)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:647)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:510)
    at com.xoom.inf.amqp.TlsTest.contactBrokerOverTLS(TlsTest.java:42)
```

My RabbitMQ broker is configured to negotiate tlsv1, tlsv1.1, and tlsv1.2.  Why does the TLS setup fail for tlsv1 and tlsv1.1 when the broker should support that?  The same Java client could negotiate TLSv1 with a RabbitMQ 3.3.1/Erlang R16B02 broker.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but may I suggest that you try to to debug what `ssl_handshake:select_session` returns in https://github.com/otphub/ssl/blob/master/src/tls_handshake.erl#L158 ? You can just add some logging, recompile and reload the module or use http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html to log what each function receives and returns.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your feedback.  I didn't explicitly try what you suggested, but your pointer to the Erlang client-hello code, where insufficient privileges are mentioned around cipher suites, prompted me to focus my attention on ciphers.  When I adjust my rabbitmq.config thusly https://gist.github.com/ae6rt/2fdcc46119821cf490c8f3c444bd11d4 I can successfully establish all TLS versions-connections.  I can't authoritatively answer my own question as to why, but I suspect letting erlang default to some cipher suites is not good enough with Erlang 18.3.

Comment: Great that you managed to solve this. There seems to be some changes in Erlang 18 around available ciphers: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2015-September/085913.html There also other updates to Erlang `crypto` and `ssl` applications http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_18.3.readme so could be that some defaults have changed.

Answer (score 3):

There were some regressions in the Erlang `ssl` application in the 18.3.x series. One of them caused what you are seeing: clients rejected during handshake, with `insufficient security` logged on the server-side. If I remember correctly, this appeared in patch 18.3.3 and was fixed in 18.3.4. This is not a problem from the client.

There is a regression in 18.3.2, fixed in 18.3.3, which prevented RabbitMQ from starting at all (due to a change in the representation of cipher suites).

Thus it is recommended to stay on 18.3 (the initial release) or update to 19.x.

Comment: THANK YOU! 18.3.2 seems to come standard on the current version (April '17) of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This saved me a lot of trouble when I upgraded server's version and RabbitMQ connections broke!